# Triggering a video at startup like the "Welcome Video" on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard

Do you remember the incredible​ [Welcome Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPTp-YInbJ0)​ on Mac OS X Snow Leopard? Does anyone know how all this is achieved? I mean the principle of how to get the video to play automatically the first time one tries to log in to a New Mac. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't really about Apple hardware or software, it's about how to learn to produce animations.

Comment: @Tetsujin Hello, sir. I'm not tring to learn to produce animations. I just want to know the principle how the intro video could be played automatically the first time you log in to a Mac. Of course, I know how to create such a video. I just try to archives this on macOS Sierra or OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how Apple did it, but a common solution to 'one-time only' actions is to check for the presence of a special hidden file in the user's home directory before doing them.

So in this case, you'd have a [login script](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CustomLogin.html) that checks if the file is there. If it is, do nothing. If it's not, play the video, then create the file.